# How to get the list of all values in one column excluding empty spaces in R

Tags: r

I have a data like below:

```
         Nationality    Placement State                 CY 2004 CY 2005
          Afghanistan                                      836  876
                           Alabama                         0    0                
                           Arizona                        52    142 
                           California                      101  57  
                           Colorado                        6    5   
          Albania                                          0    0
                           New York                        0    0
                            Oregon                         0    0
                           Washington                      0    0
```

if I try to list all the country name by using:  data[,"Nationality"], it gives all names including the empty field and the another value named TOTAL which stays at the very bottom of the column. How can I get only the countries name excluding the empty field and the TOTAL?

Comment: You could try `data$Nationality[data$Nationality != '']`

Comment: You should say in what form this text is currently stored and what you plan on doing with it. If it's jsut a text file the answer would take one form but if it is in an R data-object of some sore (such as produced by ftable, the answer would be quite different.

Comment: @Gary Fyi, there's `setdiff` for that.